# How to Send traces to datadog without using installing the agent?

Tags: mulesoft, datadog

I'm working on a `mulesoft` project with 3 APIs, I've created traces with spans from each process using `mulesoft's dataweave`, but I can't figure out if there's an API endpoint to send traces to.

I know there have been an endpoint that can permit this which is "https://trace.agent.datadoghq.com/v0.3/traces" you could send traces to this endpoint but it's deprecated now and it requires the agent.

How can I send the traces data to `datadog` without installing the agent?

Comment: What have you tried? Edit your question and add your code and configurations.

Comment: I tried to send logs to the logs endpoint which worked, but for traces I haven't tried anything yet since it's important that I find a way to do so without installing more dependencies, I don't have any code or configuration to share since I didn't find any to put in my code.

Comment: You shared the DataWeave script you are using to create a trace. You need to add the code you used to send the "logs to the logs endpoint".